# PyInstaller 2.1 seems to resort to dos 8.3 names when running with --onefile

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I've been trying to create a single .exe out of my python script by using PyInstaller 2.1, I've got everything working when running my .spec file without the "--onefile" option but things do seem to go wrong when I'm running with the "--onefile" option.

I've searched on stackoverflow and I found that I had I to change the paths to include the "_MEIPASS" variable. I've added the following function to my code (thanks to stackoverflow!):

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.getcwd())
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

I load my resources with:

```
data_dir = 'resources'
imageClear = resource_path(os.path.join(data_dir, 'Clear.png'))
```

My resources are included in my .spec file as:

```
a.datas += [('resources/Clear.png', "C:\\Users\\MyRealName\\Dropbox\\ProjectName\\resources\\Clear.png",  'DATA')]
```

Now onto the funny part, when I build my .exe without the "--onefile" option everything seems to work. When I build it with the "--onefile" option I get the following error:

```
Error loading Python DLL:
C:\Users\LAUREN~1\Dropbox\DIAGNO~1\PYINST~1.1\DIAGNO~1\build\DIAGNO~1\python27.dll (error code 126)
```

It seems that PyInstaller does revert to a DOS 8.3 file name which it then can't find. It however does not do this when I'm not running with the "--onefile" option. The only difference in my code between the two version should be the function as listed above.

Edit:
The python27.dll doesn't exist at that path (and it shouldn't), I'm not sure why PyInstaller is looking for it.

I've searched on Google and Stackoverflow to see if "getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.getcwd())" somehow forces DOS 8.3 filenames this but this function doesn't seem to do this.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!